# Bert model for word similarity

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm quite new to NLP, and I want to calculate the similarity between a given word and each word in a given list.
I have the following code

```
# Load the BERT model
model_name = 'bert-base-uncased'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Encode the target word and the list of words
target_word = "apple"
word_list = ["blackberry", "iphone", "microsoft", "blueberry", "pineapple"]

# Tokenization of the target word and  the list of words

target_word_encoded = tokenizer.encode(target_word, return_tensors='pt').unsqueeze(0)
word_list_encoded = [tokenizer.encode(word, return_tensors='pt').unsqueeze(0) for word in word_list]

# Pad each sequence so they have the same length
max_len = max(target_word_encoded.shape[1], max(word_encoded.shape[1] for word_encoded in word_list_encoded))
target_word_encoded = torch.nn.functional.pad(target_word_encoded, (0, 0, 0, max_len - target_word_encoded.shape[1]))
word_list_encoded = [torch.nn.functional.pad(word_encoded, (0, 0, 0, max_len - word_encoded.shape[1])) for word_encoded in word_list_encoded]

# Calculate the similarities
with torch.no_grad():
    target_word_encoded = target_word_encoded.squeeze(0)
    target_word_embedding = model(input_ids=target_word_encoded)[1]['last_hidden_state'][0]
    similarities = []
    for word_encoded in word_list_encoded:
        word_encoded = word_encoded.squeeze(0)
        word_embedding = model(input_ids=word_encoded)[1]['last_hidden_state'][0]
        similarity = torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity(target_word_embedding, word_embedding).item()
        similarities.append(similarity)

# Print the similarities
for word, similarity in zip(word_list, similarities):
    print(f"Similarity between '{target_word}' and '{word}': {similarity:.2f}")
```

with this code I got the following error **too many indices for tensor of dimension 2**

what does it means and how to fix it to get the result

Thanks in advance

I want to calculate the similarity of a given list of words using transformers "the bert model".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the similarity is a tricky word because there are different types of similarities. Especially semantic and sentimental similarities are very different concepts. For example, while good and bad are sentimental opposite words, they are semantically similar words. The basic BERT model is trained to capture the semantic similarity of the language. Therefore if you want to measure sentimental similarity, you can use BERT models for sentiment analysis. I suggest other similarity techniques for your task, like glove-embedding.

Regarding of your question, there are a couple of errors in your implementation.

1. Output of the models is a dict. When you accessed the first item, you already accessed the 'last_hidden_state'. You don't need the [1] before the 'last_hidden_state'.
2. Bert-type transformers use tokenizers that can split the word to multiple tokens. One solution for this issue, you can take the average of the tokens which is basically the average of the output except for first and last elements.
3. Your cosine similarity function will give an error when you run the code.

```
    # Calculate the similarities
    with torch.no_grad():
    target_word_encoded = target_word_encoded.squeeze(0)
    target_word_embedding = torch.mean(model(input_ids=target_word_encoded)['last_hidden_state'][0][1:-1],dim=0)
    similarities = []
    for word_encoded in word_list_encoded:
        word_encoded = word_encoded.squeeze(0)
        word_embedding = torch.mean(model(input_ids=word_encoded)['last_hidden_state'][0][1:-1],dim=0)
        similarity = torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity(target_word_embedding.reshape(1,-1), word_embedding.reshape(1,-1)).item()
        similarities.append(similarity)
```