# How to best obtain a similarity matrix of word embeddings using BERT ? (Word2Vec and GloVe give high value to antonyms, which defeats purpose)

Tags: bert-language-model

I am working on a natural language processing (NLP) project and I need to obtain a similarity matrix of word embeddings using BERT. I have tried using Word2Vec and GloVe, but they give high values to antonyms, which defeats the purpose of my project.

I have already preprocessed my text data and obtained the BERT embedding vectors for each word in my corpus using SentenceTransformer (see below), I was wondering: 1. Is SentenceTransformer appropriate for word embeddings similarity (I know the most relevant of BERT is documents as it takes advantage of context, but as I mentioned, the result defeats my purpose -- high similarity for antonyms). If this is not OK to use SentenceTransformer, can anyone suggest the best approach to obtain a similarity matrix of word embeddings using BERT that overcomes this issue? (preferably one that does not require adjusting diverging tensor dimensions)

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy

# Define a list of words
word_list = ['happy', 'sad', 'angry', 'afraid', 'joyful', 'depressed', 'furious', 'fearful']

# Load a pre-trained BERT model
model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')

# Generate embeddings for each word
embeddings = model.encode(word_list)

# Compute the cosine similarity matrix
similarity_matrix = numpy.round(cosine_similarity(embeddings),3)

# Print the similarity matrix
print(similarity_matrix)
```

I tried tried GloVe and Word2Vec embeddings (with different models, e.g., googlenews, wiki ...), which lead to the antonym issue - same for FastText. I have tried with different solutions with BERT, some provided on stackoverflow (e.g., the corrected solution here:[Bert model for word similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75531115/bert-model-for-word-similarity)), but changing the word list a little leads to further necessary adjustments - the goal would be that any words and any combinasion of words in a list could be processed.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Best wishes,
Eric